# Typed routes with object parameters on new Expo-Router v2

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, expo, expo-router

I am moving my app from react-navigation to expo-router, but I didn't find a solution to typed routes yet.

I know there is a feature that automatically types your routes following the files routes and dynamic routes like [slug].tsx.

But what if I my parameter is a object like { id, description, name, age }, how does the types are going to work? what should be the name of my file?

Please help! :)

I want push or href from <Link> to be typed with the params and route name

```
router.push({
    pathname: 'home',
    params: {
      id: 1,
      description: '',
      age: 1,
      name: ''
    }
  })
```

also receive it properly at useLocalSearchParams()

```
const Home = () => {
    const { id, description, age, name } = useLocalSearchParams();

    return <></>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this, not particularly proud of it, but it does the job. Not well tested, probably needs some fixes and adjustments depending on your usecase:

```
function useSearchParamsTyped<
  T extends Record<string, 'string' | 'number' | 'string[]' | 'number[]'>,
>(
  params: T,
): {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends 'string'
    ? string
    : T[K] extends 'number'
    ? number
    : T[K] extends 'string[]'
    ? string[]
    : T[K] extends 'number[]'
    ? number[]
    : never
} {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const result = {} as any
  for (const key in params) {
    if (params[key] === `string`) {
      if (typeof searchParams[key] !== `string`)
        throw new Error(`Invalid type for '${key}': '${params[key]}'`)
      result[key] = searchParams[key]?.toString()
    } else if (params[key] === `number`) {
      if (Number.isNaN(Number(searchParams[key])))
        throw new Error(`Invalid type for '${key}': '${params[key]}'`)
      result[key] = Number(searchParams[key])
    } else if (params[key] === `string[]`) {
      if (!Array.isArray(searchParams[key]))
        throw new Error(`Invalid type for '${key}': '${params[key]}'`)
      result[key] = searchParams[key]
    } else if (params[key] === `number[]`) {
      if (!Array.isArray(searchParams[key]))
        throw new Error(`Invalid type for '${key}': '${params[key]}'`)
      result[key] = (searchParams[key] as Array<string>).map(Number)
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Invalid type ${params[key]}`)
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hook `useLocalSearchParams()` allows you to type the return value, which should be sufficient as long as you are sure your search parameters are served with correct values.

So referring to your example I think you can do the following:

```
type SearchParamType = {
  id: number;
  description: string;
  age: number;
  name: string;
};

const Home = () => {
    const { id, description, age, name } = useLocalSearchParams<SearchParamType>();

    return <></>
}
```